# Angular Sortable events work differently than using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, sorting

I'm seeing differences in the sortable events from JQuery Sortable and Angular Sortable although my understanding is that the Angular events and options should the same as JQuery:

"All the jQueryUI Sortable options can be passed through the directive."
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

The following shows a jquery sortable. When an item is dragged and dropped an alert shows the index of the dropped item AFTER its dropped.
http://jsfiddle.net/L7jemdbh/

```
$(".sort-list-horizontal").sortable({containment: 'parent', tolerance: "pointer" })
    .on( "sortupdate", function( event, ui ) { alert(ui.item.index()); } );
```

The same sortable using Angular has the same alert however it shows the item's index BEFORE the item is dropped.
http://jsfiddle.net/zobgawqt/

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) { alert(ui.item.index()); }
};
```

Why is the Angular version different? How do I find the index after the drop?

(I also note that the containment option works in the jquery version but not in the Angular version so I've turned it off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how Angular Sortable does it job in handling event updates but one way to ensure that your procedure runs when all updates are invoked in angularjs is to wrap it in a `$timeout`.

**[FORKED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/k3tgk3zk/)**

Change:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) { alert(ui.item.index()); }
};
```

to

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) { 
       $timeout(function(){
          alert(ui.item.index()); 
       });

    }
};
```

Comment: hmm, this helped in the jsfiddle but not in my app.